# How to export an h2o model as MOJO from sparkling water in scala, to be loaded by EasyPredictModelWrapper

Tags: scala, h2o, sparkling-water

My goal is to export an h2o model trained on spark with scala (using sparkling-water), such that I can import it in an application without Spark.

Thus:

- using scala (the documentation only shows examples for r and python)
- export a model which is build using sparkling-water (h2o with spark)
- import a model in scala (without spark nor h2o cluster, only the `hex-genmodel` package)

I'm therefore using the `ModelSerializationSupport` to export, and the `MojoModel.load` to import

```
val gbmParams = new GBMParameters()
gbmParams._train = train
gbmParams._response_column = "target"
gbmParams._ntrees = 5
gbmParams._valid = valid
gbmParams._nfolds = 3 
gbmParams._min_rows = 1
gbmParams._distribution = DistributionFamily.multinomial
val gbm = new GBM(gbmParams)
val gbmModel = gbm.trainModel.get
val mojoPath = "./model.zip"
ModelSerializationSupport.exportMOJOModel(gbmModel, new File(mojoPath).toURI, force = true)
val simpleModel = new EasyPredictModelWrapper(MojoModel.load(mojoPath))
```

Fails with

```
error in opening zip file
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:220)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:150)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:121)
at hex.genmodel.ZipfileMojoReaderBackend.<init>(ZipfileMojoReaderBackend.java:13)
at hex.genmodel.MojoModel.load(MojoModel.java:33)
...
```

It seems that the mojo exporter doesn't use the same format as expected in the `hex.genmodel` (a zip apparently)

Running on h2o 2.1.23 (2.1.24 fails when building the cluster, as reported on https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/SW-776) and spark 2.1

--
update:

Using the ModelSerializationSupport class to load it's own export fails too with the same exception:

```
ModelSerializationSupport.loadMOJOModel(new File(mojoPath).toURI)
```

*H2OModel export and load*
Loading back as H2OModel (thus with sparkling-water) does work:

```
val h2oModelPath = "./model_h2o"
ModelSerializationSupport.exportH2OModel(gbmModel, new File(h2oModelPath).toURI, force = true)
val loadedModel: GBMModel = ModelSerializationSupport.loadH2OModel(new File(h2oModelPath).toURI)
```

*H2OMOJOModel export and load*
Loading it back with `H2OMOJOModel` does work (copied from implementation of `H2OGBM`):

```
val mojoModel = new H2OMOJOModel(ModelSerializationSupport.getMojoData(gbmModel))
mojoModel.write.overwrite.save(mojoPath)
H2OMOJOModel.load(mojoPath)
```

*H2OGBM export with MojoModel import*
Attempting to import using regular `MojoModel` fails though :

```
val gbm = new H2OGBM(gbmParams)(h2oContext, myspark.sqlContext)
val gbmModel = gbm.trainModel(gbmParams)
val mojoPath = "./models.zip"
gbmModel.write.overwrite.save(mojoPath)
MojoModel.load(mojoPath)
```

with the following exception:

```
./models.zip/model.ini (No such file or directory)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./models.zip/model.ini (No such file or directory)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is actually explained in the `getMojoModel` (which accepts either a `Model[_,_,_]` or `Array[Byte]`) on `ModelSerializationSupport`

The implementation of `getMojoModel(Model[_,_,_])` uses a byte array to store `getMojoData(Model[_,_,_])` to, and then reads it back from that byte array.

Quick test as follows works:

```
val config = new EasyPredictModelWrapper.Config()
config.setModel(ModelSerializationSupport.getMojoModel(gbmModel))
config.setConvertUnknownCategoricalLevelsToNa(true)
val easyPredictModelWrapper = new EasyPredictModelWrapper(config)
```

Thus now we can reproduce it, on our own, but without using the `ModelSerializationSupport` class (as it is part of sparkling water).

First store the mojo data to a file:

```
val path = java.nio.file.Files.createTempFile("model", ".mojo")
path.toFile.deleteOnExit()
path.toString
import java.io.FileOutputStream
val outputStream = new FileOutputStream(path.toFile)
try {
  gbmModel.getMojo.writeTo(outputStream
}
finally if (outputStream != null) outputStream.close()
```

And then read the bytes (in another scala application):

```
val is = new FileInputStream(path.toFile)
val reader = MojoReaderBackendFactory.createReaderBackend(is, MojoReaderBackendFactory.CachingStrategy.MEMORY)
val mojoModel = ModelMojoReader.readFrom(reader)
val config = new EasyPredictModelWrapper.Config()
config.setModel(mojoModel)
config.setConvertUnknownCategoricalLevelsToNa(true)
val easyPredictModelWrapper = new EasyPredictModelWrapper(config)
```

Comment: how can one switch between a `import ai.h2o.sparkling.ml.models.H2OMOJOModel` to a `hex.genmodel.MojoModel`?